# Подсчет следующего листа идет с 0. А нужно что бы продолжался

Tags: python-3.6

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import fitz
import xlwt
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from datetime import datetime
import time
import pyexcel
from tkinter import messagebox

start_time = datetime.now()  # Начало отсчёта времени

book = xlwt.Workbook('utf8')
root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x200")
root.title("Все 13 файлов")

fil = filedialog.askopenfiles()  # Окно открытия файла
fp = str(fil)  # Перевод с list в str
for i, g in enumerate(fp.split(',')):  # Разделяет значения  по 
запятой
    print(i, g)  # Выводит количество листов
    for d in fil:
#       if len(fil) != 13:
#       messagebox.showinfo('Информация', 'Вы выбрали неправильное количество файлов.Нажмите ок, начните заново')
#       break

with fitz.open(d) as doc:
    for page in doc:
        z = page.get_text()
        v = z.split()
        for i, g in enumerate(v):
            print(i, g)

s = (datetime.now() - start_time)
print('Время выполнения :', s)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Где, что? В каком месте кода проблема?

Comment: Здравствуйте при вводе нескольких пдф документов он последующий документ считает как  новый с 0  , а для программы нужно что бы он продолжал данные со 2 листа считать дальше . У меня не получается это сделать. Можете подсказать ? Обобщая ,  мне данные из 13 листов нужны как будто с 1 листа,